# How to generate a RSA 1024 key and SHA256 signature in objective-C which can be verified in java?

Tags: java, ios, objective-c, rsa, sha256

I want to generate RSA 1024 public/private keys and then use this private key along with the message (let's say "abcd" for example) to generate a SHA256 signature. I want this to be verified on java backend server.

I have created RSA 1024 keys and signature using this: `kSecKeyAlgorithmRSASignatureMessagePKCS1v15SHA256`, the keys generated are valid but I am unable to verify them in java.